# Get cat parameter from admin-ajax

Tags: plugin-development, wp-admin, jquery, ajax

I have a [plugin that restricts the categories](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/restrict-categories/) users can view/edit in the admin.  All works fine in WordPress 3.0.1, but as I started testing 3.1 I noticed that the category filter, which is AJAX, allows you to bypass the restrictions.  I'm able to filter this out in 3.0.1 because it's submitted via URL parameters.  My trouble is being able to $_GET the 'cat' parameter from the new AJAX request.  I have tried testing for $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'], but it doesn't register.

I've asked this question on the wp-hackers mailing list, but no one can give me actual code that helps with my predicament.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For excluding terms of a taxonomy the better way to do that would be to use the hook that was created for doing term exclusions.. `list_terms_exclusions`

Get the available categories using `get_terms` (get_categories calls get_terms anyway IIRC), and do your exclusions using a hook on `list_terms_exclusions` and your code should work as expected..

You can see the hook i'm referring to on line 1040.
http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/taxonomy.php

**NOTE:** Your plugin does not have a sanitization callback function when it calls [register_setting](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_setting), your options won't get sanitized properly without one, i'd strongly advise you declare a callback function and sanitize the data as appropriate (especially if you're passing that saved data into queries).

Comment: I'm not trying to exclude terms from any taxonomy listings.

Comment: Categories are terms(of the category taxonomy) and your plugin aims to exclude/filter categories, no?

Comment: The goal of the plugin is to only query posts with selected categories on the Edit Posts screen.  Yes, I am trying to exclude categories but not from any taxonomy lists.  My code works as expected EXCEPT when AJAX is used and all I need to make it work is somehow get the 'cat' parameter that is being passed through admin-ajax.php.

Comment: All the same, did you try the suggestion? I'd imagine the ajax  calls still do term retrieval using the same functions, in theory the filter should work for the ajax requests to. I could be wrong, but should only take minutes to try..

Comment: Yeah, I tried the suggestion (once I figured out how to do it) and all works.  You are right that it's a better way because it removes the selected terms from any term lists.  I appreciate the help!